# Navigate from a file in views folder to another file in views folder in laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I am new to laravel and struggling with the basics.Could anyone help?

I want to navigate from `index.blade.php` to `dashbaord.blade.php` in laravel. Both `index.blade.php` and `dashboard.blade.php` are located like this in the resources folder

```
resources/cutups/
       index.blade.php
       dashboard.blade.php
```

Tried using

```
href="{{ route('cutups.dashboard') }}">Create
```

but result in an error

Comment: Put your `index.blade.php` in `resources/views/cutups folder` and then `href="{{ route('cutups.dashboard') }}">` in your `index.blade.php`  file for linking.

Comment: thanks for that...it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Laravel documentation all the view files must be in `resources/views`.
Of course you can use more folders under that folder. For example

```
resources/views/cutups/
     index.blade.php
     dashboard.blade.php
```

When you create a new `page/view`, to access it you actually need to do 2 things:

```
1. create that page in folder `resources/views/*`
2. create a route in folder `routes/web.php`
```

and then you can open it through the browser.

For your example to open this link `<a href="{{ route('cutups.dashboard') }}">Create</a>`

1. Create that view (you already created it).
2. Create this route in web.php file

   ```
   Route::get('/cutups/dashboard', function () {
      return view('cutups/dashboard');
   });
   ```

and now you can open it with a click on your link.

Comment: You can accept and vote my answer or vote only if it helped :)